# How to allow Chrome Kiosk App configuration access for administrators?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I'm building a Chrome kiosk app that will be in a public space.  Users can interact with the app, but there are a variety of settings (server addresses, timeouts, etc.) that need to be set.  I'm looking for a strategy on how to allow access to that administration config.

1. On first run  - This is straightforward, but I want administrators to be able to pull it up again.
2. Detect if the app ran as a kiosk app or manually - This would kind of work, not sure if it's the greatest
3. Detect some key combination - Ctrl + Alt + Something switches over to the settings page, this feels like people could stumble on it accidentally.

Is there another approach I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

If your Chrome device(s) is managed you have a further option which is to use the *Chrome App Management* area within the Google Apps admin interface.

To do this you code your app to use the [storage.managed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/storage) API and this should allow a *Configure* section for your app within *Chrome App Management*.

I haven't tried this myself yet but this appears to be the way the [Chrome Sign Builder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sign-builder/odjaaghiehpobimgdjjfofmablbaleem) app is configured with its schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to have an administrator login button in a corner of the app. You can set a default password for administrators, which could then be changed in the settings dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can also think of combining suggestions you have made, first run and then a key combination, and this could bring up a password prompt as also suggested. For an example of this see the [Zebradog Kiosk app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban) which is in [GitHub](https://github.com/zebradog/kiosk) so you can see code of how this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> at boot. This allows me to login and make changes. I know you have to do a couple of reboots, but it is out of service during admin time anyway.